Varnish Setup for Gitlab Registry
Hi I'm trying to cache container registry with varnish
My current setup is like this
Gitlab Rails --> varnish_node:6081 --> nginx:80 --> OpenStack s3:6780
Whenever I set Rails machines to access nginx directly I can successfully fetch objects in s3 but when I set the varnish node in Rails I get 403 error
Here's my dummy configurations
default.vcl
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Set the client IP address in a custom header
    set req.http.X-Client-IP = client.ip;
    set req.backend_hint = default;

}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Remove or modify any headers that may cause authorization issues
    unset beresp.http.X-Some-Header;
}

nginx.conf

upstream hpc {
     server hpc.example.com:6780 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;

}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
        server_name hpc.example.com;

    location / {
                proxy_pass https://hpc;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;   
    }

}

nginx.logs
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2024:21:59:12 +0300] "GET /stage-primary-glb-registry?list-type=2&max-keys=1&prefix= HTTP/1.1" 403 193 "-" "docker-distribution/v3.39.2-gitlab (go1.17.6) aws-sdk-go/1.40.7 (go1.17.6; linux; amd64)" "10.20.20.21:6081" "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=6f1bfb7443cc45b5a16e5a1cbc1e7976/20240508/mars/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=4a1b957d696d27a9a9d1ca5942e6c241486567a983a2815c78334ac9625002e7" "10.20.20.20"

 *   << Request  >> 221
 *   Begin          req 220 rxreq
 *   Timestamp      Start: 1715194922.190385 0.000000 0.000000
 *   Timestamp      Req: 1715194922.190385 0.000000 0.000000
 *   VCL_use        boot
 *   ReqStart       10.20.20.20 35344 a0
 *   ReqMethod      GET
 *   ReqURL         /stage-primary-glb-registry?list-type=2&max-keys=1&prefix=
 *   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
 *   ReqHeader      Host: 10.20.20.21:6081
 *   ReqHeader      User-Agent: docker-distribution/v3.39.2-gitlab (go1.17.6) aws-sdk-go/1.40.7 (go1.17.6; linux; amd64)
 *   ReqHeader      Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=6f1bfb7443cc45b5a16e5a1cbc1e7976/20240508/mars/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=2bbffe23574c9f771fdf87b7ba9823cd5720d301142a9fa015fd09c68d048313
 *   ReqHeader      X-Amz-Content-Sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
 *   ReqHeader      X-Amz-Date: 20240508T190202Z
 *   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
 *   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 10.20.20.20
 *   ReqHeader      Via: 1.1 glb-s-adp-rails-primary-4 (Varnish/7.5)
 *   VCL_call       RECV
 *   ReqHeader      X-Client-IP: 10.20.20.20
 *   VCL_return     pass
 *   VCL_call       HASH
 *   VCL_return     lookup
 *   VCL_call       PASS
 *   VCL_return     fetch
 *   Link           bereq 222 pass
 *   Timestamp      Fetch: 1715194922.257731 0.067345 0.067345
 *   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
 *   RespStatus     403
 *   RespReason     Forbidden
 *   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
 *   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 08 May 2024 19:02:02 GMT
 *   RespHeader     Content-Type: application/xml
 *   RespHeader     Content-Length: 193
 *   RespHeader     x-amz-request-id: tx0000033f0ecab4cc0e4a6-00663bcc2a-17b6ba11-default
 *   RespHeader     accept-ranges: bytes
 *   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 221
 *   RespHeader     Age: 0
 *   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 glb-s-adp-rails-primary-4 (Varnish/7.5)
 *   VCL_call       DELIVER
 *   VCL_return     deliver
 *   Timestamp      Process: 1715194922.257737 0.067352 0.000006
 *   Filters
 *   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
 *   Timestamp      Resp: 1715194922.257767 0.067381 0.000029
 *   ReqAcct        579 0 579 337 193 530
 *   End
 * List item


If Nginx works and Varnish doesn't based on the configuration you shared, you should mimic the behavior of Nginx by adding the same headers to Varnish.
I see an X-Real-IP header, and an X-Forwarded-Proto header that are missing. If that is the reason you're getting the 403, you should add them to Varnish.
However, the 403 error itself is a bit abstract. I advise you to look into the logs of that GitLab setup and check why the 403 is begin generated.

Is the authorization header not being properly passed?
Is it an IP address mismatch?
Is it related to X-Forwarded-Proto that is missing?
Or is there another error in the logs that explains what's going on?

Try to send the same headers as Nginx first, and look in GitLab logs to see if there's more contextual information available.

Here are my configurations
when I change the regex for debugging purposes it works correctly. But somehow I get 403 in vcl_recv if the condition works.  I've suspected that partial content causes the problem

as you see in varnish log content-range somehow broke authorization if I'm wrong please correct me

@IeuD your logs only display client-side transactions (the -c option of varnishlog). I'm also interested in the backend transaction, maybe it contains useful information. Please omit -c and include a request and a backend request transaction for completeness.

here's output of varnishlog -b link

and here's the output of varnishlog -b when I remove req.url regex
link

@IeuD while you're showing me some valid backend requests, there is no direct correlation between client-side & backend-side transactions. I see a mix of 200 & 206 responses, but it's tough to match them. Can you just do sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/stage-primary-glb-registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/root/test/_manifests/tags/0.0.2/current/link'" ? This will include both client & backend transactions.
